# getmousestate function Open BGI library

Tags: c, bgi

I am currently using the out of date open BGI library for C as that is what my uni wants us to do but I can't figure out how to use this function.

`extern void getmousestate(g_mousestate *state);`

Definition:

```
void getmousestate(g_mousestate * state)
{
    CHECK_GRAPHCS_INITED
    state->x = sharedStruct->mouseX;
    state->y = sharedStruct->mouseY;
    state->buttons = sharedStruct->mouseButton;
}
```

g_mousestate Definition:

```
typedef struct mousestate {
    int x, y;
    int buttons;
}g_mousestate;
```

sharedStruct definition:

`static SHARED_STRUCT * sharedStruct;`

SHARED_STRUCT Definition:

```
typedef struct
{
  int mouseX, mouseY;
  int mouseButton;
  int keyCode;
  int keyLetter;
  int visualPage;
} SHARED_STRUCT;
```

The sort of thing I was trying to do to call:

```
g_mousestate *a;
getmousestate(a->x);
```

But I don't know what to initialize a to...

I assumed this function could tell me what position the mouse is in and what buttons are being pressed etc, but I can't figure out how to call the function properly. Very much a beginner here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As `a` is a pointer to a mouse state, you must have memory for the mouse state itself. Either declare one as an auto variable, or use malloc to allocate one. And you can't do a `getmousestate(a->x);` because `x` is not a mouse state structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, beginner, let's start. You want to do:

```
g_mousestate *a;
getmousestate(a->x);
```

to get the x-position of the mouse. First note that you have declared `a` as a pointer, but no memory has been allocated for it (it points to nothing yet). So first you must have memory for the `g_mousestate` object:

```
g_mousestate a;
getmousestate(&a);
```

Now `a` is no longer a pointer but an object and you pass a pointer to the `getmousestate` function by taking the address of `a` with the `&` operator ("address-of").

You need to do no more since, if you look at the definition of the function, you see that all members are filled in by it.